# update SQL database with PHP

Tags: javascript, php, sql, database, sql-update

I'm trying to apply a like button to reactions in my website. So the value of likes has to be updated, when someone hits the "like button". I watched several tutorials and searched the whole web for a solution, but I can't find it. My database don't update.

heres my code:

```
mysqli_query($db_conx, "UPDATE status SET like='$like' WHERE osid='$statusid' LIMIT 1");
```

Comment: **WARNING**: When using `mysqli` you should be using parameterized queries and [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add user data to your query. **DO NOT** use string interpolation to accomplish this because you will create severe [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/).

Comment: Can you provide any error messages?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
 mysqli_query($db_conx, "UPDATE status SET like='".$like."' WHERE osid='".$statusid."' LIMIT 1");
```

Answer (score 0):

try

```
mysqli_query($db_conx, "UPDATE `status` SET `like` = '$like' WHERE `osid` = '$statusid' LIMIT 1");
```

Make sure you put your field name between ``, so that mysql will consider them as fields, not as operators.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is

```
...SET like=...
```

'like', 'status', 'timestamp' etc are reserved sql statement so if you must use them as field name, you have to put them in the  marks eg

```
...SET `like`='$like'...
```